# Unable to update Multi-Select Picklist via Apex (INVALID_OR_NULL_FOR_RESTRICTED_PICKLIST_

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, error-messages

I have a Multi-Select Picklist that is being updated from a Lightning Component. I have a server-side apex class that is handling the logic for updating the field after user input.

What is frustrating is that for SOME (not all) options for the Multi-Select Picklist are returning INVALID_OR_NULL_FOR_RESTRICTED_PICKLIST, bad value for restricted picklist: MyPicklistValue : MyPicklist.

Now I have confirmed that the String I am passing is an EXACT match with the entry on the Picklist. All other values for the same picklist are being saved correctly with no errors. It is only for this specific picklist value.

```
for (String str : mStrings) {
                        System.debug(str);
                        Map<String, Object> objectMap = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(str);
                        String lbl = (String) objectMap.get('label');
                        Integer k = entriesHashMap.get(lbl);
                        PicklistEntry e = entries.get(k);
                        if (objectMap.get('isSelected')==true) {
                            nEntries.add(e.label);
                        }else if (objectMap.get('isSelected')==false) {
                            rEntries.add(e.label);
                        }else {
                            System.debug('ERROR OCCURED WITH FIELD' + str);
                        }
                        message = 'FIELD IS EMPTY - UPDATED FIELD';
                    }
```

Comment: Do you have record types defined?

Comment: Yes they are currently defined

Comment: Are the picklist values added to the field for that particular record type?